# Combine different JavaScript objects in one object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have four different JavaScript objects. I want to send all these four objects as one to my view layer.

Here is the code:

```
var pending=[];
var approved=[];
for (var key in rdata) {
    if (rdata.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var obj = rdata[key];
        for (var prop in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                if(obj[prop].statusEnum=="PENDING"){
                    pending.push(obj[prop]);
                }else if(obj[prop].statusEnum=="APPROVED"){
                    approved.push(obj[prop]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So here I got two objects "pending" and "approved" which I want to wrap into one single object separately with some keys to the view layer, so that I can use it at different places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily just create a single object with two lists 'pending' and 'approved', javascript is excellent for using and manipulating objects, it is good to take advantage of that

`var list = {'pending':[], 'approved':[]}`

then in your `for in` loop you can do:

`list['pending'].push(obj[prop])`

and

`list['approved'].push(obj[prop])`

Comment: it would be helpfull for me if can you give me alternate solution which could possibly improve the performance and much faster than this???@Aditya